# How to change "CDMA Network Selection" setting to "Home", by default?

Tags: android, cdma

I have to make changes to CDMA setting implementation on an Android device. By default the "Automatic" option is selected in the dialogue appeared in the select network option in the device, but I have to force it to select "Home" option by default. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

On cdma devices you might be able to modify nv item 442 ie NV_ROAM_PREF_I

https://community.republicwireless.com/thread/2736

This program will allow you to change it(but you may have to use the script tab in the latest version)

http://code.google.com/p/cdmaworkshoptool/